# Exercise from Atiyah about flatness

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

This is an exercise from Atiyah.

Let $N$ be a flat $B$-module, and $B$ a flat $A$-algebra where $A$ is a commutative ring with unit. Then $N$ is flat as $A$-module

Any hint ?

Comment: $M$ is flat if and only if $M\otimes_R-$ is an exact functor on $\textbf{R-Mod}$. You should probably be able to express $N\otimes_A-$ in terms of things you know are exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a short exact sequence of $A$-modules.  If you tensor with $B$, then by flatness you will have a short exact sequence of $B$-modules.  If you tensor with $N$, then you will again have a short exact sequence of $B$ modules.  But $M\otimes_A N\cong M\otimes_A(B\otimes_B N)\cong (M\otimes_A B)\otimes_B N$, and so the two step process is the same as tensoring with $N$ as an $A$-module.

Comment: Is the last expression $(M\otimes_A B)\otimes_{B} N$ ( tensoring with respect to $B$ ) ?

Comment: Yes.  I will edit accordingly.